# Magento admin url showing 404

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am new in magento. I have installed new module in magento and in backend it is showing 404 page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the solution of this question is very simple like :

You need to Logout and again login once installed new module in admin (Magento).

Then Clean/Flush magneto cache from admin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just **Logout and Login** in magento admin so it will not redirect 404.